# Pandas dataframe - have column with list of strings

Tags: python, list, pandas, join, dataframe

I have a dataframe on this format:

```
    id  val
0   294 aa
1   254 bb
2   844 cc
```

I need the 'val' column to be a list with the string inside, since I need to join the dataframe with another dataframe with this format:

```
id  val
0   294 [aa]
1   254 [bb]
2   844 [cc]
```

Anyone know how I can accomplish this? It has to be a list, seeing as the other dataframe is the format of our DB, which I want to insert the joined dataframe into.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I advise against storing non-scalar types but if you insist you can use `apply` and construct a list for each row:

```
In [53]:
df['val'] = df['val'].apply(lambda x: [x])
df

Out[53]:
    id   val
0  294  [aa]
1  254  [bb]
2  844  [cc]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
df['val'] = [[x] for x in df['val'].values.tolist()]
print (df)
    id   val
0  294  [aa]
1  254  [bb]
2  844  [cc]
```

But better is using scalar, for remove list is best `str[0]`:

```
print (df)
    id   val
0  294  [aa]
1  254  [bb]
2  844  [cc]

df['val'] = df['val'].str[0]
print (df)
    id val
0  294  aa
1  254  bb
2  844  cc
```